# (Spivak) consequence of a partition of unity

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Immediately after the proof of Theorem 3-11, Spivak said that only finitely many $\varphi\in\Phi$ are not $0$ on $C$. I don't understand how this could happen. Indeed, by compactness of $C$, there are finitely many $V_x$ that cover $C$. But what next? Please give me a hint. Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $x \in C$ there is an open set $V_x$ containing $x$ and a finite set $\Phi_x \subset \Phi$ such that $\phi (y)=0$ if $y \in V_x$ and $\phi \notin \Phi_x$. $C$ is covered by the open sets $(V_x)_x\in C$ because every point $x$ of $C$ is in the corresponding $V_x$. By compactness there is a finite subset $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ of $C$ such that $C \subset \cup_{i=1}^{n} V_{x_i}$. Let $\Phi_0=\cup_{i=1}^{n}  \Phi_{x_i}$. Then $\Phi_0$ is a finite set. If $y \in C$ and $\phi \notin \Phi_0$ the $y \in V_{x_i}$ for some $i$ and $\phi \notin \Phi_{x_i}$ so $\phi (y)=0$. Thus all $\phi$'s which are not in the finite set $\Phi_0$ vanish at every point of $C$.